# Where are the header files & libraries of the OpenSSL package that comes with macOS?

Tags: postgresql, macos, compilation, openssl, libressl

I just installed macOS Catalina version 10.15.4 (19E287).

It comes with OpenSSL (well actually LibreSSL) installed.

```
$ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

I'm installing PostgreSQL from source "with support for SSL (encrypted) connections", by supplying the `--with-openssl` command line option to `configure`.

> ```
> --with-openssl
>
>     Build with support for SSL (encrypted) connections. This
>     requires the OpenSSL package to be installed. "configure" will
>     check for the required header files and libraries to make sure
>     that your OpenSSL installation is sufficient before proceeding.
> ```

So where do I tell the compiler to look for the "required header files and libraries"?

Ie, what do I put for the `--with-includes` and `--with-libraries` command line options to `configure`?

> ```
> --with-includes=DIRECTORIES
>
>     "DIRECTORIES" is a colon-separated list of directories that will
>     be added to the list the compiler searches for header files. If
>     you have optional packages (such as GNU Readline) installed in a
>     non-standard location, you have to use this option and probably
>     also the corresponding "--with-libraries" option.
>
>     Example: --with-includes=/opt/gnu/include:/usr/sup/include.
>
> --with-libraries=DIRECTORIES
>
>     "DIRECTORIES" is a colon-separated list of directories to search
>     for libraries. You will probably have to use this option (and
>     the corresponding "--with-includes" option) if you have packages
>     installed in non-standard locations.
>
>     Example: --with-libraries=/opt/gnu/lib:/usr/sup/lib.
> ```

I don't want to use Homebrew. I'd rather install LibreSSL from source if I must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not present anymore because it has been deprecated. Either you inckudde your own library or if you want to link against macOS own libraries (`libssl` & `libcrypto`) you should use the corresponding header files for this version. You can find the sources from Apple [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL098/).

Comment: [This thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/3897) also said that OpenSSL headers were removed starting from 10.11 (El Capitan). Really sad to learn that; I guess I have to install them myself.

Comment: I think unfortunately this directory is useless for Catalina which has LibreSSL 3.3, not 0.9.8